# How to save Numpy 4D array to CSV?

Tags: python, csv, numpy, keras

I am trying to save a series of images to CSV file so they can be used as a training dataset for Alexnet Keras machine learning. The shape is (15,224,224,3).

So far I am having issue doing this. I have managed to put all data into a numpy array but now I cannot save it to a file.

Please help.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I don't think saving it to a csv file is the correct way to do this, it's used for 1d or 2d data to create a table-like structure, so I'm going to offer another solution. You can use `np.save` to save any numpy array to a file;

```
np.save('file_name', your_array)
```

which can then be loaded using `np.load`;

```
loaded_array = np.load('file_name.npy')
```

Hope that this works for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using pickle to save the data. It is much more diverse and easy to handle compare to np.save.

Comment: Note that [pickle is considered as not secure](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/pickle.html).